# Why golang coroutines have different performance results

Tags: go

```golang
type MapInt map[int]int
var cacheMap unsafe.Pointer //Cach,

func Test_Atomic(t *testing.T) {
    //runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            m1 := MapInt{}
            m1[3] = i                                           //write data
            atomic.StorePointer(&cacheMap, unsafe.Pointer(&m1)) //Atomic Opt
        }
    }()
    //read
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go func() {
            m := *(*MapInt)(cacheMap)
            md := m[3]
            t.Log(md)
        }()
    }
    t.Log("end ")
}
```

I got two result

1. The first one got an error

=== RUN   Test_Atomic
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0xaff344]

2. The second is to run successfully

   ...
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:31: end
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   atom_test.go:28: 999
   --- PASS: Test_Atomic (0.15s)
   PASS

Comment: It's pretty hard to say something about your question because there are so many problems with your code:  "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" is not a different result, its a trivial programming error you made. Fix that before doing anything else. Package atomic is not for endusers. Keep away, there be dragons. Package unsafe is well, unsafe. Your code is not going to be faster by magically using unsafe. Keep away from unsafe at all cost.

Comment: I am trying go for Lock_Free programming,This code is simulating One writer, multiple readers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the (nondeterministic) order in which the concurrent code actually executes, the first read may execute before the first write, causing the nil dereference panic. You need to ensure that `cacheMap` has a usable value in it before the first read executes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm curious about its execution order, because I don't quite understand the priority of coroutines in go. Is there any documentation that I can refer to?

Comment: @Cyberhan Goroutines are unprioritized.